# tcolorbox with fancyvrb Verbatim inside enumerate

Tags: positioning, enumerate, tcolorbox, fancyvrb

[image: tcolorbox inside enumerate]

I have a fancyvrb Verbatim environment inside a tcolorbox. When I use that tcolorbox as an item in an enumerate environment, the item number goes inside the tcolorbox. For example, the second item in the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newtcolorbox{codebox}[1]{
box align=top,
colback=white!5!white,
colframe=white!75!black,
title=#1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem.
  \item
   \begin{codebox}{Swap}
      \begin{Verbatim}
   Hello. 
      \end{Verbatim}
    \end{codebox}
  \item Epsum.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How can I bring the number out of the tcolorbox?

Comment: Welcome here yang5!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image: more-or-less-aligned box]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\newtcolorbox{codebox}[1]{
  colback=white!5!white,
  colframe=white!75!black,
  title=#1,
  box align=top,
  before skip=-\baselineskip
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Lorem.
  \item \mbox{}
  \begin{codebox}{Swap}
    \begin{Verbatim}
   Hello.
   \end{Verbatim}
  \end{codebox}
  \item Epsum.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I'm sure `tcolorbox` must have an option for aligning to the title somewhere (or using `T` alignment`) as it has options for everything else. But I couldn't see anything obvious ....